# How to remove N+1 queries from my Rails association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails app I have the following associations:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :payments

  def sales_volume(range)
    payments.in_range(range).sum(&:amount)
  end

  ...

end
```

---

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :person

  def self.in_range(range)
    select { |x| range.cover?(x.date) }
  end

  ...

end
```

In my controller I am doing...

```
@people = Person.all.sort_by { |p| p.sales_volume(@range) }
```

...and it works.

Unfortunately, though, it generates a lot of **N+1 queries**.

Is there a way to show the sales volume per `person` without generating a separate SQL query for each person?

---

*Addition:*

I've already tried eager-loading...

```
@people = Person.all.includes(:payments).sort_by { |p| p.sales_volume(@range) }
```

...but that didn't work either. Still the same number of queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

`@people = Person.all.includes(:payments).where(payments: { date: range }).sort_by { |p| p.payments.sum(&:amount) }`

The idea is to put the range condition directly in the eager load association and change the way you're making the sum to avoid running the query again.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations

Comment: Doesn't work. I should have mentioned that I already tried that.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I ended up using your solution. It removes all the N+1 queries.

Answer (score 5):

First, let's rewrite that `in_range` method in `ActiveRecord`

```
def self.in_range(range)
  where(date: range)
end
```

Now, that `sales_volume`. Let's say

```
def self.with_sales_volume(range)
  joins("LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.user_id = users.id").
    merge(Payment.in_range(range)).
    group('users.id').
    select('users.*, SUM(payments.amount) AS sales_volume')
end
```

Lastly

```
@people = Person.from(Person.with_sales_volume(@range), :t).order('t.sales_volume DESC')
```

This is the idea. I've done it so many times but it's really hard without trying and having all the info. I think you can fix it in case. If you're using rails 5 you can use `left_joins`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution looks like the most technically advanced. And that's probably why I couldn't get it to work in my case :-)

Comment: Nice, I'm not sure I knew you could pass a range into a where clause like that!

Comment: Me neither. I tried yesterday. Rails takes care of it :)

Answer (score 4):

The answer from ursus should be correct but I wanted to provide some additional information about the code you wrote.

The `select` you're doing in your `self.range` method is an Enumerable or Array method which operates on the query after it's been run which is one reason you're seeing so many queries. [Enumerable#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)

A `select` in ActiveRecord actually selects which columns you want to retrieve:

```
Person.select(:id, :name) # only returns the columns id & name
```

You want to perform a `where`:

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person

  def self.in_range(range)
    where('date between ? and ?', range.begin, range.end)
  end
end
```

This gives you the ability to do:

```
Person.first.sales_volume(Time.zone.today - 30.days..Time.zone.today)
```

That only works on a single Person though (which still may be useful).

If you want to perform that type of query on the collection you'll need something a little more complex, as ursus pointed out.

```
people =
  Person.
    select('people.*, SUM(payments.amount) AS sales_volume').
    joins(:payments).
    merge(
      Payment.
        in_range(
          (Time.zone.today - 30.days)..Time.zone.today)
        ).
    group('people.id')

people.first.sales_amount # prints sales amount
```

You can convert all this into your `with_sales_volume` method as ursus noted.

Comment: Thanks for the nice write-up. I found it very helpful.